# Get(Store) a String value in multiple String variables

Tags: java, android, arraylist, file-io

I'm working with Java Files class. This is my code logic-

```
if ((file.getName().contains("pictures"))) {

        //trying to get path of files

         String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

I'm searching for files named "picture" in a folder(and sub-folders) and get it's path. This code does returns paths but that are all stored in a single variable called `path` . What i'm trying to do is get all paths and store it in a Array of variables.

This is the output i get-

```
D/path: /sdcard/DCIM/picture001.jpg
D/path: /sdcard/DCIM/picture0421.jpg
D/path: /sdcard/DCIM/picture4341.jpg
D/path: /sdcard/DCIM/picturs01.jpg
```

Now, i want all these paths to be stored in different variables,rather than just one variable `path` like

```
   path1=/sdcard/DCIM/picture001.jpg
    path2=/sdcard/DCIM/picture0421.jpg
    path3=/sdcard/DCIM/picture4341.jpg
```

What i tried doing is by-

```
ArrayList<String> myarray= new ArrayList<>();
 myarray= path;
```

But this gives error. How do I achieve it?

Comment: what is the exact value of String path you are getting

Comment: Rather than trying to assign a string to an array list, use its `add` method - `myarray.add(path);`

Comment: @Sundeep The code below "This is the output i get"

Comment: I still coundn't get it work..

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays {


        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            String path = "/sdcard/DCIM/picture001.jpg /sdcard/DCIM/picture0421.jpg /sdcard/DCIM/picture4341.jpg /sdcard/DCIM/picturs01.jpg";
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(path);
            ArrayList<String> myarray= new ArrayList<>();
            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                myarray.add(scan.next());
            }

            for(int i=0; i<myarray.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(myarray.get(i));
        }

        }

}
```

Comment: "D/path:" has nothing to do with this since its the logcat statement. So using delimiter on it is of no use.

Comment: As you said it is the exact String so i use Delimiter if "D/path: " is not there you can remove that statement.

Comment: And also, it returns "s" which contains path which is exactly same as "path". i want them to stored in multiple varaibles like path1,path2, path3 and so on

Comment: so what are the actual problems you are facing

Comment: I want them to be stored in multiple varaibles like path1,path2, path3 and so on.

Comment: you mean array am i right like path[0], path[1], path[2],...etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173297/discussion-between-sundeep-and-mukesh).

Comment: Exactly, thats what i need..But it gives error. I'm trying myarray[1];  butit gives error saying "Array type expected;found java.util.ArrayList..

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.io.*;

     class JavaFile{

            public static void main(String args[]){

                String path[]=new String[1000];
                int count=0;

                File f=new File("/Users/Study/Desktop");

                if(f.exists()){

                    String list[]=f.list();

                    for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){

                            if(list[i].contains("Sc")){
                                path[count]=new File(list[i]).getAbsolutePath();
                                count++;
                                System.out.println(list[i]);
                            }

                    }



                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Not Found");

            }


    }
```

Comment: Also checkout if that f.isDirectory() than repeat this same thing. Hope it helps.